owl carousel video progress bar
for a school project I'm trying to create a carousel consisting of both images and video, but I can't seem to find specific documentation to insert a progress bar in slides that have a video. Is it possible to create this progress bar? Can anyone suggest an option to implement this? Thank you very much in advance to anyone who wants to help me


var videoSlider = $('.owl-carousel');
videoSlider.owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  margin: 0,
  nav: false,
  dots: false,
  dotsContainer: '.owl-dots',
  autoplay: false,
  items: 1
});

videoSlider.on('translate.owl.carousel', function(e) {
  $('.owl-item .item video').each(function() {
    // pause playing video - after sliding
    $(this).get(0).pause();
  });
});

videoSlider.on('translated.owl.carousel', function(e) {
  // check: does the slide have a video?
  if ($('.owl-item.active').find('video').length !== 0) {
    // play video in active slide
    $('.owl-item.active .item video').get(0).play();
  }
  
  else {
    setTimeout(function () {
       $('.owl-next').trigger('click');}, 10);
  }
});

$(".video-item").on('ended', myHandler)

function myHandler(ev) {
  // there is no method 'next'
  // so we will fake a click
  $('.owl-next').trigger('click');
}


window.onload = (function() {
// Get the position on the page of the SVG
var svgLocation = document.querySelector(".owl-carousel").getBoundingClientRect();

// Scroll offset that triggers animation start.
// In this case it is the bottom of the SVG.
var offsetToTriggerAnimation = svgLocation.y + svgLocation.height;

// Function to handle the scroll event.
// Add an event handler to the document for the "onscroll" event
function scrollAnimTriggerCheck(evt)
{
  var viewBottom = window.scrollY + window.innerHeight;
  if (viewBottom > offsetToTriggerAnimation) {
    if ($('.owl-item.active').find('h4')) {
          setTimeout(function () {
       $('.owl-next').trigger('click');}, 1000);
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
    
    // Remove the event handler so it doesn't trigger again
    document.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollAnimTriggerCheck);
  }
}

// Add an event handler to the document for the "onscroll" event
document.addEventListener("scroll", scrollAnimTriggerCheck);
});

$('video').on('mouseover mouseout', function(e) {
  const evt = e.type;
  if (evt === 'mouseover') {

        this.pause();
  }
  if (evt === 'mouseout') {
    this.play();
  }
});
/* ---------------- */
/* HTML Reset Stuff */
/* ---------------- */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  background: #222;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  margin: 30px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

button span {
  color: white;
}

video {
  max-width: 100%;
}

/* --------------- */
/* Content Wrapper */
/* --------------- */
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

/* ----------------- */
/* Owl Styling Stuff */
/* ----------------- */
.owl-carousel {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.owl-item {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 220px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.owl-nav {
  font-size: 60px;
}

.owl-next {
  float: right;
}

.owl-carousel.owl-loaded {
    position: relative;
}

.owl-dots {
    position: relative;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

button > img {
  width:50px;
}
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plyr/3.4.8/plyr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plyr/3.4.8/plyr.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<header>
  <h1>Owl Slider - Play / Stop / Continue HTML5 Video</h1>
</header>
<main class="wrapper" style="margin-top:2000px;">
  <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
   
    <div class="item"><h4 class="photo">1</h4></div>
    <div class="item">
      <video id="myVideo" class="video-item" muted>
        <source src="https://ak9.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/5007479/preview/stock-footage-christmas-snow-globe-snowflake-with-snowfall-on-blue-background.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="https://ak9.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/5007479/preview/stock-footage-christmas-snow-globe-snowflake-with-snowfall-on-blue-background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-delay="1000"><h4 id="myPhoto">3</h4></div>
    <div class="item">
      <video class="video-item" muted>
        <source src="https://ak4.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/1014705914/preview/stock-footage--rd-happy-anniversary-text-greeting-and-wishes-card-made-from-glitter-particles-from-golden.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
    <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
    <div class="item">
      <video class="video-item" muted>
        <source src="https://ak9.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/1027722329/preview/stock-footage-ramadan-candle-lanterns-are-hanging-on-dawn-sky-background-with-glowing-stars-and-a-crescent-there.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="https://ak9.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/1027722329/preview/stock-footage-ramadan-candle-lanterns-are-hanging-on-dawn-sky-background-with-glowing-stars-and-a-crescent-there.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="owl-dots">
      <button role="button" class="owl-dot active"><img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/15745/15745651.png"></button>
      <button role="button" class="owl-dot"><img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/15745/15745651.png"></button>
      <button role="button" class="owl-dot"><img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/15745/15745651.png"></button>
      <button role="button" class="owl-dot"><img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/15745/15745651.png"></button>
  </div>

</main>



